# Custom Table Cell View doesn't get modified when load table data

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, nstableview, nstableviewcell

I have a little problem with a custom `NSTableCellView`.

**The problem**: I have a Table View in a Nib with all stuff configured as well to load data from an array. For now, is OK. The problem is, while the app is preparing the views (using method `(id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row`), the returned View is modified as I want (watched by a breakpoint before return), but the View that I can see, that everybody can see, is not modified.

I expect you could help me found the problem. I give you some stuff to help to understand my problem.

**Some Images**

*Cell before get returned, as you can see, the View is modified as well.*

[image: Cell before get returned]

*Cell displayed in the Table View, in this case, the Custom View is not modified, it's look likes I didn't modified anything*

[image: Cell that everybody can see]

**Code**

My custom `NSTableCellView`, there's only a header...

```
@interface playlistQueueItemView : NSTableCellView
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSButton *button;
@property (strong) IBOutlet NSTextField *title;
@property (strong) IBOutlet NSTextField *artist;

- (void)setAllFromInitWithTitle:(NSString*)title artist:(NSString*)artist;
@end
```

Method for create the Views for the table:

```
- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
    playlistQueueItemView *cell = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:tableColumn.identifier owner:self];
    NSDictionary* song = [[PlaylistQueue getQueue] getSongWithPos:(int) row];

    cell.artist.stringValue = song[@"artista"];
    cell.title.stringValue = song[@"titulo"];

    return cell;
}
```

One more thing, I followed a bit one of the Apple's sample projects, called TableViewPlayground.

Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to override `- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row` and then return the view.

In `- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row` you can return a model object that has the value you want to populate.

[source](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/PopulatingView-TablesProgrammatically/PopulatingView-TablesProgrammatically.html)

Comment: thanks :D. I didn't realize about the difference between these two methods. Now works as well